# to_json not working because reflections are wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have  a class called **Foo** that looks like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to othermodel 
end
```

and a class **Bar** that looks like this:

```
class Bar  < Foo 
   belongs_to thirdmodel
end
```

When i try to serialize bar with : bar.first.to_json(:include 
=> :othermodel), it fails in production mode. Strangely it works in 
the development environment. I digged around and found that the 
bar.first.class.reflections.keys only includes "thirdmodel" and not 
"othermodel" in production mode.

I can't explain that, in rails 2 and in the development environment it 
works prefect.

The error is :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `macro' for nil:NilClass
   from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:41:in `block in serializable_add_includes'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was Thinking Sphinx. Removed it and replaced it with own solution and now it works perfectly.